# Downloading Python Modules

Tags: python-3.x

I just installed Python3.4.2 yesterday on Windows 7. I tried typing out the command to download and install modules in the system terminal but I got Syntax Error. Within the terminal I typed: pip install pyPdf. Just wondering what my issue was.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, pyPdf is 2.x package

The raise syntax in Python 3.x no longer accepts comma-separated arguments

here is porting guide from 2.x to 3.x

http://docs.pythonsprints.com/python3_porting/py-porting.html

Comment: pyPdf was just an example. I've tried a few different modules e.g numpy, beautifulsoup etc. None of them worked

Comment: Well, not sure about other modules, but I really tried pyPdf with my python 3.4.2 and clearly exception syntax was old, from 2.x day